Resources for creating opening books or chess trees offline on PC
Please Suggest resources for creating, viewing and updating opening books or chess trees offline on PC. preferably with the ability to add moves or lines manually and with open source or free software only.

I found this page rebel13.nl
with some promising reading but i was unable to download the file poly17a.7z to see what it can do and I was not able to open bin books with arena also
the search continue for me
banksia and scid are next and of course what obs are?

Arena Chess GUI can do this from every PGN file or manually. But I would be very surprised if you didn't find this using the Search.

Ok I'll try it and get back to you.

An additional tip when trying Arena: The GUI gives full statistics of an opening book, but if you want those to be displayed you have to import or add entire games from a PGN which start from the initial position. You can also enter positions in the book from EPD files and continue editing them, but then the book statistics will not show-up.

Chessbase or Droidfish would be my options.

chessbase is not free droidfish is not for pc

Nobody pays chessbase and everyone uses chessbase.

And Droidfish can be used on PC. E.g. by bluestacks.
